# convert jQuery method to delegated one

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

so in my HTML page i have some of the markup generated dynamically according to AJAX calls. Here is what I currently have(Minimal code):

```
<div class='container'></div>
<script>
  // AJAX call. On success --> (<div class='content'></div>) within ".container" is generated
  $('.content').slideToggle(0);  // Not working
</script>
```

Right now I have the divs generated but, I want all `.content` divs to be toggled at first when they are loaded. any idea how to achieve this?

Please note that the AJAX call is triggered multiple times according to other events. including `$('.content').slideToggle(0)` inside the success function of the AJAX call causes `slideToggle` to behave inversely .

Comment: Your "minimal code" seems a bit *too* minimal.  That code should successfully target that one `div` element.  When you dynamically add more `div` elements, simply target the new ones in the AJAX success call once they're added.

Comment: @David , Please can you explain this in more details. question updated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer below is already explaining.  If you need to perform an action on an element that gets added dynamically then you need to perform that action *after* the element is added.  This would happen in the `success` callback of the AJAX operation.  See how the code in your question first has a `div` and then toggles that `div`?  Your AJAX callback would be conceptually very similar.  First it adds the `div` to the page and the it toggles the `div`.

Comment: Lets assume i did as @pepeevich suggested, lets also assume i an running AJAX calls using the following code `setInterval(ajax_call, 300000);`. so when the AJAX call is first invoked all `content` divs are slideToggled (closed) but, 5 minutes later they are all (expanded).I already tried adding `slideToggle()` inside the success function. but what i really want is get around this issue if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should call slideToggle method when ajax request completed and html element is already generated, imho.

```
$.ajax({ url: "some_url",
    success: function(){
       // add html element in DOM
       $('.content').slideToggle(0):
    }});
```

Comment: Thank you @pepeevich . That's what I thought, but, the AJAX call is being triggered multiple times according to other events which causes the slideToggle to behave inversely. I thought that maybe there is another way using jQuery `.on()` or such. any idea?

Comment: Could you desribe your task in a question description? Maybe you need a pass complete callback to slideToggle() and don't prevent toggle if previous toggle isn't completed?

Answer (score 0):

> convert jQuery method to delegated one

You seem to be over-thinking the problem.  What you have is simply a set of operations happening in a different order than you expect.  Keep in mind that AJAX is *asynchronous*.  So when you do this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your_url.ext",
  success: function (response) {
    // add the response to the DOM
  }
});
$('.content').slideToggle(0);
```

The `slideToggle` is actually happening *before* anything in the `success` function.  Since you want to target the elements added in the `success` function, simply move that operation to where you want it to happen:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your_url.ext",
  success: function (response) {
    // add the response to the DOM
    $('.content').slideToggle(0);
  }
});
```

Additionally, if this AJAX operation happens multiple times and you want to target *only* the elements returned by that call (not elements previously added to the DOM) then you'd need to further identify the target elements in your jQuery selector.  Clearly `$('.content')` is going to target every matching element in the entire DOM.  So you'd need to more narrowly target the elements you want.

How you do that depends on your HTML structure as well as what's actually being returned by the AJAX call and what you're doing with it.  For example, if you create a containing element and add the returned elements to that containing element then you can include that containing element in your jQuery selection.

This can be done a variety of ways, including parent/child selectors:

```
$('#some_element .content').slideToggle(0);
```

or using `.find()`:

```
$(someElement).find('.content').slideToggle(0);
```

or passing the element context to jQuery:

```
$('.content', someElement).slideToggle(0);
```

etc.

The point is, if you need to more specifically target your elements, then you can use jQuery to more specifically target your elements.

Comment: Thank you @David for your great effort :))